# Add mask border after masking UIImageView with mask property

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3, mask

I managed to get a mask for a UIImageView from a png using the `.mask` property but was wondering if there was any simple way to draw a border around the mask.

**What it looks like:**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN6z7.png)

**Code (UICollectionViewCell)**:

```
lazy var maskingView: UIImageView = {

    let view = UIImageView()

    view.image = UIImage(named: "mask")
    return view
}()

lazy var profilePictureContainerView: UIImageView = {

    let containerView = UIImageView()

    containerView.backgroundColor = .black
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return containerView
}()

override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()
    maskingView.frame = profilePictureContainerView.bounds
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)        
    profilePictureContainerView.mask = maskingView
    setUpViews()
}
```

`setUpViews()` is a func simply laying out a Collection View Cell and positioning the `profilePictureContainerView` inside it.

**What I want to achieve**

Put a border, say red, around the black shape (i.e., the mask's "interior edge").

Any ideas ?

Comment: Given that your shape is quite complex and custom, I'd say there is no straightforward way to achieve this. The easiest way to do this would be to create the border shape as a separate image and overlay it atop your `profilePictureContainerView`. This will still enable you to change its color via `tintColor` property on `UIImageView`, just remember to mark the image to render as template image in assets (https://krakendev.io/blog/4-xcode-asset-catalog-secrets-you-need-to-know)

Comment: @Losiowaty: was indeed thinking about doing what you said as a workaround. Definitely quick to do, thank you for reminding me to mark image as template (pretty sure I would have forgotten about it). Works just fine !

Answer (score -1):

Did you try with layer?

```
maskingView.layer.borderWidth = 1 // Or any width 
maskingView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: This would give a rectangular border, around the view.

Comment: @Losiowaty exactly, was about to reply just that.